# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined

Tags: nodejs

espero anden bien, estoy iniciando con backend en un curso. Desarrollando el siguiente cod

```
const fs = require('fs') 
const objectoGuardar = [{title:'toy1',price:'120', thumbmail:'vertoy.png', id: '1'},
 {title:'toy2',price:'120', thumbmail:'vertoy2.png', id: '2'},{title:'toy3',price:'120', thumbmail:'vertoy3.png', id: '3'} ] 

 fs.promises.writeFile('archivo.json', JSON.stringify(objectoGuardar),'utf8') 
    .then(() => fs.promises.readFile('archivo.json', 'utf-8'))
    .then((datos) => console.log(datos))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
    .finally(() => console.log('terminé'))

async function trabajarConArchivos() {
    try {
        await fs.promises.writeFile('archivo.json') 
        const datos = await fs.promises.readFile('archivo.json', 'utf-8') 
        console.log(datos)
        //await fs.promises.getById(console.log("id 1: ", objectoGuardar[0]))
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    } finally {
        console.log('terminé')
    }
}

trabajarConArchivos()
```

Pero me genera el siguiente error
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined

Si me ayudan por favor a obtener una guía de como solucionarlo les agradezco

Comment: Claro, es que no le estás pasando el parámetro `data` que espera el método `writeFile`. En tu llamada: `await fs.promises.writeFile('archivo.json')` dentro de la función `trabajarConArchivos`, sólo estás pasando 1 argumento de los 2 necesarios, es decir, le estás diciendo el nombre del archivo que quieres escribir, pero no los datos que vas a escribir en él. Saludos

Comment: Super bien muchas gracias